# tough string to remove from a bunch of php files using perl

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I am getting more and more bald as I yank hair out over what should be a simple thing. I have a fragment of a hack attempt left in some PHP files (100s).

The string is:

```
<?*god_mode_on*/eval(base64_decode("")); /*god_mode_off*/ ?>
```

And I thought that using a perl command line such as:

```
perl -pn -i.bak -e "s{<\?\*god_mode_on\*/eval\(base64_decode\(""\)\); /\*god_mode_off\*/ \?>}{}g;" `find . -name '*.php'`
```

Would neatly produce a backup and strip the string out but it seems to carefully avoid doing so. I think I may have perl blindness now as I have been looking at it for so long so hopefully someone might directly see the problem and let me know how slow I've been ;-)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting an error? In what way is it failing? Anyway you should really restore your files from a backup rather than attempt to remove a hack in this manner.

Comment: You have double quotes inside your double-quoted string.

Comment: There was no error, just no change. If the site was mine we would have a backup ;-) I can do a fair bit of reconstruction and close up the obvious holes in the service and setup. Nothing is perfect but at least it was known to have been hacked, plenty out there that don't even know. Thanks to all for responding so quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping track of everything that needs to be escaped is not simple. It looks like you have not escaped your double quotes inside a double quoted string, for example. Perl has the [`quotemeta`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#quotemeta) function that helps you figure this out:

```
print quotemeta '<?*god_mode_on*/eval(base64_decode("")); /*god_mode_off*/ ?>';

===>  \<\?\*god_mode_on\*\/eval\(base64_decode\(\"\"\)\)\;\ \/\*god_mode_off\*\/\ \?\>
```

Within a regular expression, the `\Q` escape will invoke `quotemeta` on everything up to the next `\E` escape, so you can say:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e \
  's{\Q<?*god_mode_on*/eval(base64_decode("")); /*god_mode_off*/ ?>\E}{}g' \
  `find . -name '*.php'`
```

Notice that I used single quotes instead of double quotes for the argument to the `-e` command-line switch. Otherwise, you would also have to worry about the shell interpolating your input and opening up a whole other can of worms.

(Also, the `-pn` switch is redundant -- it is sufficient to use `-p`)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that whatever shell you are using is interpreting the backslashes? You may need to escape them (with another backslash) so they actually get passed to perl as backslashes.